# how do you get children count from Firebase in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm trying to find out how many children my key has but when I try using

```
var count = 0

ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        count += snapshot.childrenCount
    })
```

It gives me an error. How should I be doing this?

Comment: If you just want children count, then use  ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value...   then  self.childCount = snapshot.childrenCount.  Leaving it like it is will continue to feed events to your app when something in any of the nodes changes, and it will continually update count. So if there are 3 children, count = 3, but then something changes, say a node is added, then count = 3 + new child count. So every time something changes in the node, count will be incremented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's weird... what you posted works for me... maybe the DataObject is not what is expected... Test this by adding a breakpoint and seeing what snapshot is.

You can try this instead... it should yield same result as the one that doesn't work for you, so maybe it won't work either:

```
snapshot.value.count
```

EDIT:
Ah, I think I know why you're not able to get the children count property! Try casting snapshot to FDataSnapShot! So try

```
ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) in
        count += snapshot.childrenCount
    })
```

Comment: Did you mean FIRDataSnapshot?

Comment: Nope. I meant FDataSnapshot. Though, it seems in the new Firebase 2.0 SDK, it changed to FIRDataSnapshot.